# How many times is a particular row present?

Tags: python, pandas

I am just starting to look at Pandas and trying to work out how to calculate how many times a particular row is seen.  I need to add a new column showing how many times a duplicate row is seen and show only the unique rows.

So this:

```
team    runs  
team 1   5  
team 1   5  
team 1   5  
team 2   5
```

Would become this:

```
team    runs occurrences   
team 1   5      3  
team 2   5      1
```

Comment: 1. What is the question.
2. Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy once you figure out what an identical row means. I simply use the hash of the stringifed values. If you have an alternate definition then that would work as well.

```
In [37]: df = DataFrame({'A' : [1,1,1,2,3,3], 'B' : [2,2,2,2,3,3]})

In [38]: df
Out[38]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  1  2
3  2  2
4  3  3
5  3  3
```

Compute a hash for each row. Identical 'rows' yield identical hashes

```
In [39]: hashed = df.apply(lambda x: hash(str(x.values)), axis=1)

In [40]: hashed
Out[40]: 
0    4112993419872972622
1    4112993419872972622
2    4112993419872972622
3    7113020419917972579
4    6113011419891972603
5    6113011419891972603
dtype: int64
```

Map the value counts back to the original indexes. You can pass `take_last=False` to `.drop_duplicates()` if you want the first unique row (rather than the last)

```
In [41]: hashed.drop_duplicates().map(hashed.value_counts())
Out[41]: 
0    3
3    1
4    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is great, many thanks Jeff.  This gives me the line number and the amount of occurrences.  How do I append the original columns to this data so I can see the original data and not just the line number please?

Comment: Or perhaps a better way for me to ask the question is as follows:  When this maps the value counts back to the original indexes can the original data also be seen?

Comment: i would simply groupby and count then

Comment: Is this something I do after the above or a different way to approach the task?  Can you please show me how this is done?

Comment: ask a new question - it's instead of the above

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
In [39]: hashed = df.apply(lambda x: hash(str(x.values+1)), axis=1)

In [40]: hashed
Out[40]: 
0    4112993419872972624
1    4112993419872972626
2    4112993419872972628
3    7113020419917972579
4    6113011419891972603
5    6113011419891972603
dtype: int32
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).